# Почему assertEquals fails для одинаковых значений?

Tags: java

В тестах я сравниваю два объекта Orders. Они выглядят идентично, но не равны.
Equals везде переопределила

```
Expected :Orders{id=0, customer=Customer{id=1, name=Oleg}, checki=Checki{id=0, totalCost=200.0}, status=OrderStatus{id=31, name='NEW'}, item=[FoodItem{id=11, itemName_='Sosiska', price=20.0, description='Norm', category_id=1, inStock=true}, FoodItem{id=21, itemName_='Sosiska', price=20.0, description='Norm', category_id=1, inStock=true}]}
Actual   :Orders{id=0, customer=Customer{id=1, name=Oleg}, checki=Checki{id=0, totalCost=200.0}, status=OrderStatus{id=31, name='NEW'}, item=[FoodItem{id=11, itemName_='Sosiska', price=20.0, description='Norm', category_id=1, inStock=true}, FoodItem{id=21, itemName_='Sosiska', price=20.0, description='Norm', category_id=1, inStock=true}]}
```

Класс Orders

```
@Entity
public class Orders {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.ALL})
  private Customer customer;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
          optional = false,
          cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(unique = true)
  private Checki checki;


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_status")
  private OrderStatus status;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinTable(name = "order_item",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
  )
  protected Set<FoodItem> item=new HashSet<FoodItem>();

...

@Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Orders orders = (Orders) o;
    return id == orders.id &&
            Objects.equals(customer, orders.customer) &&
            Objects.equals(checki, orders.checki) &&
            Objects.equals(status, orders.status) &&
            Objects.equals(item, orders.item);
  }
```

Класс Customer

```
@Entity
 public class Customer {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
...
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Customer customer = (Customer) o;
        return id == customer.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, customer.name);
    }
```

Класс Checki

```
@Entity
public class Checki {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private double totalCost;
...
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Checki checki = (Checki) o;
        return id == checki.id &&
                Double.compare(checki.totalCost, totalCost) == 0;
    }
```

Класс OrderStatus

```
@Entity
public class OrderStatus {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "status", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Orders> orders = new HashSet<>();
...
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrderStatus that = (OrderStatus) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                Objects.equals(orders, that.orders);
    }
```

Класс FoodItem

```
@Entity
public class FoodItem {
  
  @Id
  private long id;
  private String itemName_;
  private double price;
  private String description;
  private long category_id;
  private Boolean inStock;
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "item")
  private Set<Orders> orders = new HashSet<>();
...
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    FoodItem foodItem = (FoodItem) o;
    return id == foodItem.id &&
            Double.compare(foodItem.price, price) == 0 &&
            category_id == foodItem.category_id &&
            Objects.equals(itemName_, foodItem.itemName_) &&
            Objects.equals(orders, foodItem.orders) &&
            Objects.equals(description, foodItem.description) &&
            Objects.equals(inStock, foodItem.inStock);
  }
```

Сам тест

```
public void testGetTestEntity() {
        log.info("Test Get_______________________________");
        OrderStatus orderStatus = new OrderStatus(32, "NEW");
        Customer customer=new Customer(02,"Oleg");
        Checki checki=new Checki(2, 200.0);
        FoodItem meal1=new FoodItem(12,"Sosiska",20.0,"Norm",1,TRUE);
        FoodItem meal2=new FoodItem(22,"Sosiska",20.,"Norm",1,TRUE);
        Orders orders =new Orders(customer,checki,orderStatus);
        orders.getMeals().add(meal1);
        orders.getMeals().add(meal2);
        instance.addEntity(orderStatus);
        instance.addEntity(checki);
        instance.addEntity(meal1);
        instance.addEntity(meal2);
        orders.setId(checki.getId());
        Optional<Long> result = instance.addEntity(orders);
        Optional<Orders> saveOrder = instance.getById(Orders.class, result.get());
        assertEquals(orders, saveOrder.get());
    }
```

Comment: У вас проблема с кодом, но вы не показали код. Без вашего кода тут не о чем говорить.

Comment: @tym32167 добавила

Comment: классы, что вы используете, типа `Customer`, `Orders`, `Checki`, `OrderStatus` тоже реализуют equals? У вас в вашем методе `public boolean equals` какое именно условие не выполняется?

Comment: вы знаете, что `double` - число с ограниченной точностью?  `Double.compare` может [вернуть false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081911/312041) для вроде бы одинаковых значений.

Comment: @tym32167 да, я в курсе. Но как тогда проводить тесты для таких типов

Comment: я же ссылку кинул, там написано как сравнивать double - задать какую то погрешность

Comment: @tym32167 попробовала, не помогло. Полностью убрать сравнение по полям этого типа тоже не помогает. Значит, дело не в этом

Comment: повторю вопрос - У вас в вашем методе public boolean equals какое именно условие не выполняется?

Comment: @tym32167 я не понимаю вопроса, не проходит тест из-за одного из equalsов. Какого-я  не знаю

Comment: удаляйте эти equalsы один за другим, пока не заработает. Как заработает, добавляйте пока не сломается. Так и узнаете, что не рпботпет у вас.

Comment: Попробуйте `assertTrue(orders.equals( saveOrder.get()));
`

Comment: Возможно, проблема в сравнении коллекций. Попробуйте их убрать из `equals` методов. Если после этого будет работать - попробуйте не через Objects.equals коллекции сравнивать, а, например, вручную пройдясь в цикле по всем элементам.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, действительно в них была проблема. спасибо,заработало